# Left join with variable in Zend Framework 2 Select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm trying to do the following select in Zend Framework 2:

```
$select->from($this->table);
    $select->join($this->multiLangTable, $this->table . '.id=' .$this->multiLangTable . '.'
            . $this->foreignKey .' AND '. $this->multiLangTable . ".lang =".$locale, $mapping, 'left');
```

The variable $locale is the language of my application (ca, es, en). The problems is that the app shows and error saying :

> Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column 'ca' in
>   'on clause')

It detects the variable as a column, but it's not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me.

```
 $select->from($this->table);
 $select->join($this->multiLangTable,new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression( $this->table . '.id=' .$this->multiLangTable . '.'
            . $this->foreignKey . ' AND '.$this->multiLangTable . '.lang = ?'), $mapping, 'left');
 $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

 $resultsSql = $statement->execute(array($locale));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the same before but havent really found a good way to do it. this is because Zend just qoutes everything in the on statement as identifiers. You can just move the condition to the where statement

```
$select->from($this->table);
$select->join($this->multiLangTable, $this->table . '.id=' .$this->multiLangTable . '.'
            . $this->foreignKey, $mapping, \Zend\Db\Sql\Select::JOIN_LEFT);
$select->where(array($this->multiLangTable . ".lang" => $locale));
```

Or you can use a `\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` in the on statement, but this will remove all the qouting from it.

```
$select->join($this->multiLangTable,new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression($this->table . '.id=' .$this->multiLangTable . '.'
        . $this->foreignKey .' AND '. $this->multiLangTable . ".lang = ? ", $locale), $mapping, 'left');
```